# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-unpack-0odmg2ak/filelock-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl'

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, oserror

I recently noticed this issue while installing packages in a virtual environment.
Nothing has changed in the `requirements.txt` file or in the python version recently.

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-unpack-vv8j9n04/chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
```

The error is always slightly different (it always refer to a different package), eg:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-3x7hynv0/1b12fd6675aa4decf8fb81ec8bf37a69ee5e7e5a8195846d4c3fa6da'
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-w9dzvide/b92d40499b6302da0a2b1139431fdf8ab53286285c9bfa3069348897'
...
```

Some info from the setup:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
$ python --version
Python 3.8.
$ python -m pip --version
pip 21.3.1
```

Any idea of that can be going on? All my searches pointed to issue on Windows due to a max path length of 260 chars, but that shouldn't be an issue on Ubuntu

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you figured out what your issue was? I just ran into the same issue in one of our CI pipelines.

Comment: For me, it looks like that I could solve the issue by re-running the pipeline. Not a satisfying answer, but it helped me.